# Android SIP Client Multiple Profiles

Tags: android, sip

I'm making a SIP application and I need multiple profiles in it .

But I can only register 1 profile, once I register the second profile the registration will failed and will give me the SipErrorCode: -9 (IN_PROGRESS) .

Is there a way to register 2 Profiles at the same time ? Is it possible ?

This is how I register my SIP:

```
public SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile me = null;
```

///....

```
    if(manager == null) {
        manager = SipManager.newInstance(getActivity());
    }
```

///...

```
    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        me = builder.build();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mainActivity, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        manager.open(me, pendingIntent, null);

        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                Log.e("onRegisterR", "Registering SIP... " + localProfileUri);
            }
            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                Log.e("onRegisterS", "Registration Successful! " + localProfileUri);
            }
            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                             String errorMessage) {
                Log.e("onRegisterF", errorMessage);
            }
        });
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        Log.e("ParseException", pe.getMessage());
    } catch (SipException se) {
        Log.e("SipException", se.getMessage());
    }
```

ps. I just implemented this code twice to make 2 Profiles

Comment: You could handle the whole SIP Stack by yourself by using libraries like pjsua or linphone. I've personally had bad experiences with the android internal sip stack and resorted to using pjsua. SIP is a pretty complex/big protocol and therefore the libraries are pretty big and complex as well.

Comment: I'm having a hard time building / debugging this other complex libraries :/